# command line thumbnailing

Tags: thumbnails

I have a whole folder of photos I want to look at as thumbnails, and I'd like to do it by calling one of GNOME's native thumbnailers individually, namely `totem-video-thumbnailer` or `evince-thumbnailer`, and piping them through a backend (I hear `gstreamer` is possible, but anything that allows me to manually call forth a whole foldersworth of thumbnails from the command line will do).

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/199110/how-can-i-instruct-nautilus-to-pre-generate-pdf-thumbnails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this polaroid.sh-Skript:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# jpg-Dateien in Vorschau umwandeln.
#
montage -size 256x256 './*jpg' \
    -thumbnail 128x128 \
    -set caption '%t' \
    -bordercolor AliceBlue \
    -background grey20 \
    -polaroid 0 \
    -set label '' \
    -background white \
    -geometry +1+1 \
    -tile 4x  $1.html && firefox ./$1.html
```

Maybe you can adopt some ideas. The basic command `montage` is in the ImageMagick package, which is easily installed:

```
 apt-get install ImageMagick
```