# Generate thumbnails for text?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, thumbnails

I need to generate thumbnails for some text files. 
Obviously the system somehow has the ability to do exactly this (see the screen shot). Is there any way I can access these images and just copy them for later use?

Or is there a special command (tool) for this?

[image: somefolder.png]

I looked at this:
[command line thumbnailing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36945/command-line-thumbnailing)

And this:
[How can I instruct Nautilus to pre-generate thumbnails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199110/how-can-i-instruct-nautilus-to-pre-generate-thumbnails)

Which were useful but none could deal with text.

Comment: @Rmano, what size would the icons need to be?

Comment: @JacobVlijm The idea is to create a thumbnailer --- the basic form is `script -s width input_url output_file` which is the format used by nautilus. See for example http://rlog.rgtti.com/2011/11/24/xfig-thumbnailers-with-gnome3nautilus3/ and the linked page...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Using Imagemagick to create text icons

Based on the same principle as [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/556769/72216), the script below creates a text icon from a text file with the help of Imagemagick.

The color of the rounded background image and the text color can be set in the head of a script (as well as a number of other properties).

[image]

*What it does* 
It reads the textfile, takes th first four lines (set in `n_lines = 4`), the first seven characters (set in `n_chars = 10`) of each line, and creates an overlay over an image of the size, set in e.g. `psize = "100x100"`.

#### How to use

The script needs `imagemagick` to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then:

1. Copy the script into an empty file
2. Save it as `create_texticon.py`
3. set in the head section:

   - the color of the icon's background
   - the color of the icon's textlayer
   - The size of the created icon
   - The number of lines to show in the icon
   - The number of (first) characters per line to show in the icon
   - The path where to save the image
4. Run it with your textfile as an argument:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/create_texticon.py </path/to/textfile.txt>
   ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import math

temp_dir = os.environ["HOME"]+"/"+".temp_iconlayers"
if not os.path.exists(temp_dir):
    os.mkdir(temp_dir)

# --- 
bg_color = "#DCDCDC"                                # bg color
text_color = "black"                                # text color
psize = [64, 64]                                    # icon size
n_lines = 4                                         # number of lines to show
n_chars = 9                                         # number of (first) characters per line
output_file = "/path/to/output/icon.png"            # output path here (path + file name)
#---

temp_bg = temp_dir+"/"+"bg.png"; temp_txlayer = temp_dir+"/"+"tx.png"
picsize = ("x").join([str(n) for n in psize]); txsize = ("x").join([str(n-8) for n in psize])

def create_bg():
    work_size = (",").join([str(n-1) for n in psize])
    r = str(round(psize[0]/10)); rounded = (",").join([r,r])
    command = "convert -size "+picsize+' xc:none -draw "fill '+bg_color+\
              ' roundrectangle 0,0,'+work_size+","+rounded+'" '+temp_bg
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])

def read_text():
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as src:
        lines = [l.strip() for l in src.readlines()]
        return ("\n").join([l[:n_chars] for l in lines[:n_lines]])

def create_txlayer():
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", "convert -background none -fill "+text_color+\
                      " -border 4 -bordercolor none -size "+txsize+" caption:"+'"'+read_text()+'" '+temp_txlayer])

def combine_layers():
    create_txlayer(); create_bg()
    command = "convert "+temp_bg+" "+temp_txlayer+" -background None -layers merge "+output_file
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])

combine_layers
```

Comment: Is this solution persistent?

Comment: What do you mean by persistent? The script creates the icons, or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I mean does this "thumbnails" is persistent after rebooting system or temporally (need to rerunning the script)?

Comment: Thye script only creates the thumbnails, once set, it will be persistent, but setting the icons will not be the problem (of the question) I guess?

Comment: @Kasiya To use it as a thumbnailers, see http://rlog.rgtti.com/2011/11/24/xfig-thumbnailers-with-gnome3nautilus3/ and http://rlog.rgtti.com/2010/11/28/adding-a-gnomenautilus-thumbnailer/ --- Nautilus will update it automatically. Nice idea; now just thinking about using `pygment` to syntax highlighting it and it will be perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Rmano I will look into the links! (probably not today). In the meantime, I edited the script a bit. The (re-) naming section for bulk creating icons will follow.

Comment: @JacobVlijm not needed. Just drop the script in the correct place and write the `/usr/share/thumbnailers/...` file and the icons will automagically appears, and be managed by system (cached, updated on file changes, etc.)

Comment: @Jacob to be more specific --- the thumbnailer system will call the script with the arguments `-s size input-url output-file.png`. the size is 16, 32, 48 ... etc (as in icons themes), and the `input-url` will be something like `file://path/to/the/file.txt` --- the script is supposed to leave in `output-file.png` the thumbnail.

Comment: @Rmano that is clear. One question: with 16 and probably 32 px there will probably not much to read (visually). should the script change `n-lines`, `n_caharacters` automatically?

Comment: @JacobVlijm whatever --- I got the idea. I think that the answer is sufficient as it is. A pity we can't leverage the system way of doing it, but I start supposing it's hard coded in some low-level library.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I might post an edited (ready-to-use) version tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

## Idea :

convert the text file to **pdf** and use `pdfdraw` to generate the thumbnail.

> unoconv is a software that converts between various documents that the OpenOffice office suite understands.

Advantage of this method : Bulk thumbnails for almost all document can be generated easily by creating a script.

See [gist](https://gist.github.com/panuta/1897940) for the steps .

1. Install OpenOffice headless package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install  openoffice.org-headless  openoffice.org-java-common  openoffice.org-writer  openoffice.org-calc  openoffice.org-impress
   ```
2. Install UNO python library

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-uno unoconv
   ```
3. Install necessary fonts (Especially for international language)

   Copy fonts to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/` Then run `fc-cache`
4. Run OpenOffice as a service

   ```
   soffice -headless -nofirststartwizard -accept="socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.Service"
   ```
5. Convert document to PDF using unoconv command

   ```
   unoconv -f pdf __[filename]__
   ```
6. Create PDF thumbnail by using MuPDF tool

   ```
   pdfdraw -r 100 -o __[output-thumbnail]__ __[pdf-file]__ 1
   ```

similiar question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523267/how-to-convert-pptx-files-to-jpg-or-png-for-each-slide-on-linux)

Comment: Hmmm... text file are NOT wordprocessor files. There is a quite basic misconception here. Text file are program sources, logs, just ".txt" fles, etc. Office documents and PDFs have their thumbnails working ok.

Comment: @Rmano: Going via PDF is a technique often used by ECM software when generating previews, even for formats that noone would usually convert to PDF, such as log files. So, this is a good idea.