# How to make a thumbnail for xmind file

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

I have installed Xmind in Ubuntu 18.04 instructed by [this script](https://github.com/mriza/XMind-Linux-Installer).

But I want to create a thumbnail for Xmind filetype. I think thumbnail can be generated by an icon downloaded from the internet.

[image]

I found some threads about making thumbnails, but I don't know how does is make? 
I hope someone may explain process of making thumbnails.

[HOWTO: Thumbnails for Xmind mind map files](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1046678)
[Generate thumbnails for text?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558846/generate-thumbnails-for-text)

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do this. I can add an icon for Xmind file by setting MIME type.
According to this [thread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/how-can-i-change-the-icon-for-a-specific-file-type). 
`xmind.xml` was created under `/usr/share/mime/packages` with the content below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="application/x-xmind">
    <comment>Xmind files</comment>
    <icon name="application-x-xmind"/>
    <glob pattern="*.XMIND"/>
    <glob pattern="*.xmind"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Then I downloaded an [icon](https://www.easyicon.net/1185142-Mind_Map_Paper_icon.html).  Move the icon to `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes`

```bash
sudo mv downloaded.svg /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes/application-x-xmind.svg
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime   
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

Now Xmind file looks
[image]